# Limit drop area with Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to make a web designer **with Cytoscape**, and I'd like to set a restricted area in which the user can drop a node. In essence: the user can drop a node out of the "canvas" (just a rectangle in CSS) and they get lost. Like in the image below:

[image: Current view]

As you can see, my node is shaped as a rectangle, which can be dropped out of the zone I'm trying to limit. What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @rmdez, you will need to clarify this question further. In this state, the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a good point to start the improvement.

Comment: Regarding your question, how exactly do you think the drag'n'drop functionality should look like? Do you want to drop a node from one compound parent to another [Compound node drag-and-drop UI](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-compound-drag-and-drop)? Is this related to your question? If not, what do you want to achieve? Please clarify this in your question

Comment: Sorry about that, I think it was clear enough... What I really want to do is to forbid the user dropping the nodes out of a specific area. This is because, although I 
 had already "drawn" how big this area should be with CSS, I can move the nodes below the margins of my canvas and they get lost.

Comment: I added a picture of the problem I'm trying to describe, just in case it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet uses both the built in [`cy.fit()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.fit) function as well as the [`cytoscape-autopan-on-drag`](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-autopan-on-drag) extension.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),

    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          content: "data(id)"
        }
      },

      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
        }
      },

      {
        selector: ":selected",
        style: {}
      }
    ],

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: "n0"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n3"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n4"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n5"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n7"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n9"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n11"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n13"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n15"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n16"
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: "n0",
            target: "n1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n1",
            target: "n2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n1",
            target: "n3"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n4",
            target: "n5"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n4",
            target: "n6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n6",
            target: "n7"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n6",
            target: "n8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n8",
            target: "n9"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n8",
            target: "n10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n11",
            target: "n12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n12",
            target: "n13"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n13",
            target: "n14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n13",
            target: "n15"
          }
        }
      ]
    },

    layout: {
      name: "dagre",
      padding: 50
    }
  }));

  // demo your core ext
  cy.autopanOnDrag({
    /* Options here */
  });

  cy.on('tapdrag', 'node', function() {
    cy.fit(cy.elements(), 50);
    cy.center();
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-dagre@2.1.0/cytoscape-dagre.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-autopan-on-drag@2.2.0/cytoscape-autopan-on-drag.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```